# Can't Pass Strings Through Constructor in HiltViewModel - Error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] java.lang.String cannot be provided

Tags: android, kotlin, migration, android-viewmodel, dagger-hilt

I am migrating from Dagger 2 to Hilt in Android.  Most of my migrations have been pretty straight forward, but the last viewmodel I'm converting is giving me trouble

### ContactDetailViewModel

```
@HiltViewModel
class ContactDetailViewModel
@Inject
constructor(
    application: Application,
    contactId: String?,
    name: String?,
    refId: String,
) : NetworkBaseViewModel(application) {
    .... (non-DI related code)

    @Inject
    lateinit var client: ApolloClient

    .... (non-DI related code and references to constructor params)
}
```

### ContactDetailVMFactory

```
@Singleton
class ContactDetailVMFactory @Inject constructor(
    val application: Application,
    val contactId: String?,
    val name: String?,
    val refId: String
) : ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory(application) {
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        return ContactDetailViewModel(application, contactId, name, refId) as T
    }
}
```

### ContactDetailEditFragment

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
open class ContactDetailEditFragment: Fragment() {

    val args: ContactDetailEditFragmentArgs by navArgs()

    open val vm by activityViewModels<ContactDetailViewModel>(
        factoryProducer = {
            ContactDetailVMFactory(
                    application = requireActivity().application,
                    contactId = args.contactId,
                    name = args.name,
                    refId = args.contactId ?: args.vmKey
            )
        },
        key = { args.vmKey }
    )
        ....

    @Inject
    lateinit var client: ApolloClient



        ....
}
```

### Errors / Build Output

```
/BaseApplication_HiltComponents.java:141: error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] java.lang.String cannot be provided
without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method.
public abstract static class SingletonC implements BaseApplication_GeneratedInjector,
                        ^
    java.lang.String is injected at
        com.companyname.contacts.vm.ContactDetailViewModel(…, name, …)
    com.companyname.contacts.vm.ContactDetailViewModel is injected at
        com.companyname.contacts.vm.ContactDetailViewModel_HiltModules.BindsModule.binds(vm)
    @dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelMap java.util.Map<java.lang.String,javax.inject
.Provider<androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>> is requested at
    dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory.ViewModelFactoriesEntryPoint
.getHiltViewModelMap() [com.companyname.BaseApplication_HiltComponents.SingletonC → com.companyname
.BaseApplication_HiltComponents.ActivityRetainedC → com.companyname.BaseApplication_HiltComponents
.ViewModelC]
It is also requested at:
    com.companyname.contacts.vm.ContactDetailViewModel(…, contactId, …)
    com.companyname.contacts.vm.ContactDetailViewModel(…, refId)
```

I'm pretty baffled on this.  I've been working on it for days.  I have other strings that are being passed into other HiltViewModels that don't seem to have a problem.  I wonder if it's an issue with the ViewModelFactory.

Comment: FWIW, when I have needed to pass identifiers into a Hilt viewmodel's constructor, I have used `@AssistedInject`: https://dagger.dev/dev-guide/assisted-injection.html.

Comment: I'm not sure having `@Inject constructor` makes any sense if you create viewModel object manually `ContactDetailViewModel(application, contactId, name, refId) as T`

Comment: Also how can DI determine which `String` argument is which (`val name: String?` vs `val refId: String`), you don't use qualifiers. https://medium.com/mindorks/qualifiers-in-dagger-android-development-c0574cca87a2

Comment: You also create `ContactDetailVMFactory` object manually, so it's also pointless for it to have `@Inject constructor` (or being marked as `@Singleton` at all)

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of issues within code provided (check my comments), but I would simplify it as follows:

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class ContactDetailViewModel @Inject constructor(
    @ApplicationContext val application: Context, // cast to Application later
    val client: ApolloClient
    savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
) : NetworkBaseViewModel(application) { 

    // get fragment arguments via SavedStateHandle
    private val args = ContactDetailEditFragmentArgs.fromSavedStateHandle(savedStateHandle)

}
```

`ContactDetailVMFactory` - remove

`ContactDetailEditFragment` - use `open val vm: ContactDetailViewModel by viewModels()`.

This answer is with assumption that you don't really need to use `by activityViewModels()`, (it would be very weird if you needed to inject Fragment's arguments into Activity-bound ViewModel, <strike>though I can see why some people would want to do that</strike>)

Comment: Interesting. I wonder if there's a more centralized way to pass the args.  There are multiple fragments that use the ViewModelFactory aside from ContactDetailEditFragment. I'm still pretty new to a lot of this.  Working through your input now. Thanks very much!